# I am Married but still watch Hentai

Tags: nikah

Selamunaleykum Dear Brothers,

I am from Europe.
I am married and me and my wife are together in nights alhamdullilah. But I still watch hentai . So even for my wife thats okay. Because I am really active and my Wife isn’t as Active as I am. Is it what I am doing Haram because i try to suppress my Feeling as much as possible?
I hope you understand the Question.

Answer (score 1):

Watching those kind of materials are `zina of the eyes`

Narrated by Muslim, 2657:

Verily Allah has fixed the very portion of adultery which a man will indulge in, and which he of necessity must commit. The adultery of the eye is the lustful look, and the adultery of the tongue is the licentious speech, the heart desires and yearns, which the parts may or may not put into effect. (https://sunnah.com/muslim/46)

Quran Al-Isra (17:32)

And do not approach unlawful sexual intercourse. Indeed, it is ever an immorality and is evil as a way. (https://quran.com/17/32)